# docker compose dockerfile_inline commands not running

Tags: docker-compose

I would like to run a postgres service in a container and I need to do some preliminary setup, like creating a user and database. I put this in my `docker-compose.yml` file using the `dockerfile_inline` heading, but the lines don't run.

```
  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile_inline: >
        RUN echo "create user myuser password 'myuserpw'" | psql -U postgres
        RUN echo "create database mydb owner myuser" | psql -U postgres
    image: postgres:16.2
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mydbpassword
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-docker:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

I'm very new to compose and not sure if I am using it correctly. But I do know that I have seen this work from a regular Dockerfile. So, what do I have set up wrong that is preventing my inline dockerfile commands from running?

Comment: If you specify `build` and also an available `image` (which `postgres:16.2` is) [it uses the image and the build spec is ignored](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#using-build-and-image)